# Is this a thing in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, return, game-engine

So I want to have a function for my game engine that I am writing in java, where it will return an object of type `T`.
My code for the function goes like:

```
public <T> T getComponent(Class<T> tClass)
    {
        for(Component component : components)
        {
            if(component.getClass() == tClass)
            {
                return(T)component;
            }
        }
        return(null);
    }
```

And this works well and I can call it with
`getComponent(Component.class);`
However I want to be able to call it like I would with C# (`getComponent<Component>();`) so I am wondering if this is possible.

Telling me if its possible or not would be great and giving me code to implement it would be even better, thank you for whatever contribution you make, even if its just reading this so that more people will see it.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: In English, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not possible. Java generics were implemented with type erasure as a 0 cost addition to the existing language. You need `tClass` to do what you're doing.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your *specific* technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as thought this is not possible according to the comments so this is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought maybe using a type witness in combo with catching `ClassCastException` *might* be enough to do the trick here. Unfortunately, even then, erasure will make it impossible (to do this method *without* `Class<T>`):

```
public class Test {

    private static final List<? extends Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                            new A(), new B(), new C(), new B()));
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        B next = Test.<B>getMatchingEntity(); //Class-cast exception here
    }

    //Always returns <Test$A>
    private static <T extends Entity> T getMatchingEntity() { //<T> == Test$B
        for (Entity e : Test.entities) {
            T back;
            try {
                back = (T) e; //Assigns Test$A here
            } catch (ClassCastException badPractice) {
                continue; //never thrown! erases to <Test$Entity> instead of <Test$B>
            }
            return back; //returns first result regardless
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static class Entity {}
    public static class A extends Entity {}
    public static class B extends Entity {}
    public static class C extends Entity {}
}
```

Comment: This is way too complicated. I think I'll just do without

Comment: This is basically just a proof (via exhaustion) of it not being possible, your approach with `Class<T>` is sensiblie and correct.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't understand it so I thought that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**No, what you're trying to achieve is not possible, and I can explain why.**

Unlike C# generics, Java generics are a *compile-time* feature. This basically means that, after Java code is compiled, no information is known about the actual type of a generic argument. This is called **type erasure**, because the type of the generic argument is lost, or erased, after compile time, and it means that while you could *technically* declare a method like this in Java:

```
public <T> T getComponent() { ... }
```

And you could *technically* call that method like this (like you would in C#):

```
getComponent<YourType>();
```

You wouldn't actually be able to get the type of `T` within the method because that information does not exist at runtime, and so writing such a method would be pretty useless. In order to preserve the actual type of `T` at runtime, you need to either pass an object of type `T` to the method, or pass a `Class<T>` object as a parameter, which is what you did in your code.

The difference here ultimately just comes down to how the developers of Java and C# chose to implement generics in their language. There is an excellent comparison between C# and Java generics [here](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html) that I would highly recommend checking out if you want to learn more.

I will make just one comment on the code you provided. You're preforming an unchecked cast on this line:

```
return (T)component;
```

But, since you're passing an object of the type `Class<T>` as a parameter, you can cast like this instead:

```
return tClass.cast(component);
```

This way you can get rid of the unchecked cast warning you're probably getting from the compiler.